# Android studio wont start and causes memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, android-studio

My studio works just fine until today. I dont installed any drivers or updates in past. Android studio just wont start and it causes memory leaks. Normally when starting studio it tooks about 400-500K MB but today about 2+GB. [image: LOOK HERE] ! Does anybody know solution for this problem? I have tried restart computer, recovery system data from past, i have android 0.8.9 so i tried install new version 0.8.11 of android studio nothing works. Iam desperate...